# How to leave objects in the array with id in 1 copy?

Tags: javascript

How to leave objects in the array with id in 1 copy?
I need to leave only objects in the array without repeating id

```
  let data = [
    {id: 257, oldPoleNumber: "16056E", address: "1", jobWo: "Job6", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
    {id: 257, oldPoleNumber: "10050E", address: "2", jobWo: "Job0", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
    {id: 257, oldPoleNumber: "13053E", address: "3", jobWo: "Job3", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
    {id: 260, oldPoleNumber: "10050E", address: "1", jobWo: "Job0", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
    {id: 260, oldPoleNumber: "16056E", address: "2", jobWo: "Job6", dateWorked: "05/20/21"}
 ]


const test =data.filter(item => !data.some(el => el.id === item.id))
  
console.log(test)
```

I need

```
  let data = [
        {id: 257, oldPoleNumber: "16056E", address: "1", jobWo: "Job6", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
        {id: 260, oldPoleNumber: "16056E", address: "2", jobWo: "Job6", dateWorked: "05/20/21"}
     ]
```

Comment: How are you determining which one to keep because it's not the first instance of the id because then `260` would have an `jobWo` of `Job0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are searching again and again in the `data` array,
So this ID will always exist, thus always will return true to search.

```js
let data = [
    {id: 257, oldPoleNumber: "16056E", address: "1", jobWo: "Job6", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
    {id: 257, oldPoleNumber: "10050E", address: "2", jobWo: "Job0", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
    {id: 257, oldPoleNumber: "13053E", address: "3", jobWo: "Job3", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
    {id: 260, oldPoleNumber: "10050E", address: "1", jobWo: "Job0", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
    {id: 260, oldPoleNumber: "16056E", address: "2", jobWo: "Job6", dateWorked: "05/20/21"}
 ];

let uniqueData=[];
data.forEach((item)=>{
    isContains = uniqueData.find(it=>it.id===item.id);
    if(!isContains){
        uniqueData.push(item);
    }
})
console.log(uniqueData);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you keep track of all ids in an object while you're looping and then check if id exists already in the object and if so then don't push it to array.

```js
let data = [
  {id: 257, oldPoleNumber: "16056E", address: "1", jobWo: "Job6", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
  {id: 257, oldPoleNumber: "10050E", address: "2", jobWo: "Job0", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
  {id: 257, oldPoleNumber: "13053E", address: "3", jobWo: "Job3", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
  {id: 260, oldPoleNumber: "10050E", address: "1", jobWo: "Job0", dateWorked: "05/20/21"},
  {id: 260, oldPoleNumber: "16056E", address: "2", jobWo: "Job6", dateWorked: "05/20/21"}
]

const res = []
const trackedIds = {}

for(const d of data) {
  if(!(d.id in trackedIds)) {
    res.push(d)
  }
  trackedIds[d.id] = true
}

console.log(res)
```